# SharpPcap - Incoming packets are dropped

Tags: c#, ethernet, sharppcap

I am writing a C# application which communicates with an external device via ethernet. I am using SharpPcap Version 4.5.0 for this.

Unfortunately, I had to realize that some incoming packets are dropped. For testing, I also put a switch between the external device and my computer, which also logs every packet. On this log, the packet is visible. Hence I am quite sure that the packet is really sent (and it's not an error of the external device).

This is the code that I use:

```
public bool TryActivateChannel(uint channelNumber, out string message)
    {
        message = string.Empty;
        devices[(int)channelNumber].Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous);
        devices[(int)channelNumber].OnPacketArrival += PacketArrived;
        devices[(int)channelNumber].StartCapture();
        return true;
    }

public bool CloseChannel(uint channelNumber, out string message)
        {
            message = string.Empty;
            devices[(int)channelNumber].OnPacketArrival -= PacketArrived;
            devices[(int)channelNumber].Close();
            return true;
        }
private void PacketArrived(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Packet.LinkLayerType != PacketDotNet.LinkLayers.Ethernet)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                inputQueue.Enqueue(e);
            }
}
```

devices is just CaptureDeviceList.Instance and inputQueue is a ConcurrentQueue, which is dequeued in another Thread. This thread writes every incoming packet into a *.pcap file (where the packets are missing). Additionally, I look at the Statistics property of my ICaptureDevice, which claims that no packet is dropped. I also tried to run it on a different computer, in order to make sure it is not a problem of the network card.

At this point, I am really helpless. Did I do anything wrong in my code? Is this a known issue? I read somewhere else the SharpPcap can manage up to 3 MBit/s. I am far away from this value, hence I don't believe it's a perfomance problem.

**Addendum:** Instead of the ConcurrentQueue, I also tried the approach with the List provided by the author. There, I have the same result: Some packets are missing. I also had a version without a second Thread, where the packets are processed directly in the event handler. Same result: Packets are missing. Moreover, I captured simultaneously with Wireshark. Here, the packets are also missing. I realized that the missing packets all have in common that they have a certain length (about more than 60 bytes). For shorter packets, I never observed that they are missing. I am using WinPcap 4.1.3. Is the problem located there?

Comment: The author provided a [decent example](https://github.com/chmorgan/sharppcap/blob/master/Examples/QueuingPacketsForBackgroundProcessing/Main.cs) to work from.  The `lock` in that code is not optional.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot for your reply. I also tried this approach, but without success. See the additional information I provided in my question.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and i have an amd 3950x... so it is not a cpu problem. In my case the speed is around 15kb/s and packages are still dropping

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if you don't see the packets in WireShark, the problem is neither in your code nor in SharpPcap.
It means it's either in the hardware or in the driver/OS.

---

Common reasons that you don't receive packets:

- The packets were VLAN tagged, depending on the adapter configuration, it may drop VLAN tagged frames before they reach the OS.
- Firewall: some firewalls are capable of preventing packets from reaching the Npcap/WinPcap driver, this usually affects IP packets.
- Faulty driver: Example: The Npcap bug https://github.com/nmap/npcap/issues/119
- Packets "discarded": this means that the packet was rejected by the hardware itself,
  you can check for this using the command `netstat -e`, usual reasons:

  - Bad cables: yes, really.
  - Frame collision: occurs more frequently with half duplex cables and when the time between packets is too short.